# package dev: redispatch S3 method

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I have a package where I have S3 methods that, based on some condition needs to re-dispatch from the original method in a way that cannot be immediately solved by S3, S4, or R6.

Here's a notional package:

```r
devtools::create("~/newproj")
```

Create `~/newproj/R/func.R`:

```r
#' Some function
#'
#' @param obj some object
#' @return something
#' @export
func <- function(obj) UseMethod("func")
#' @export
func.default <- function(obj) message("I am lost")
#' @export
func.character <- function(obj) paste("5 times", obj)
#' @export
func.numeric <- function(obj) 5 * as.numeric(as.character(obj))
#' @export
func.factor <- function(obj) {
  asnum <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(obj)))
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1]] <- if (anyNA(asnum)) substitute(func.character) else substitute(func.numeric)
  eval.parent(cl)
}
```

As inane as that method is, the takeaway is that when the object is a `factor`, the action taken on it depends on whether it can be number-like or not. In reality, there are a number of candidate S3 methods to be used, and I've always found the use of `eval.parent` to be somewhat elegant, one reason being that it reduces layers on the stack. (Perhaps this is not worth the squeeze ...)

Demo:

```r
devtools::document("~/newproj")
# i Updating newproj documentation
# i Loading newproj
# Writing NAMESPACE
# Writing NAMESPACE
func(5)
# [1] 25
func("a")
# [1] "5 times a"
func(factor("5"))
# [1] 25
func(factor("a"))
# [1] "5 times a"
```

This works, but since `devtools` is permissive in its visibility of unexported functions, I'll load it as a *package*:

```r
detach("package:newproj")
devtools::install("~/newproj")
library(newproj)
func(5)
# [1] 25
func('a')
# [1] "5 times a"
func(factor('a'))
# Error in func.character(obj = factor("a")) : 
#   could not find function "func.character"
```

Which may not be too surprising, since `NAMESPACE` is just

```
S3method(func,character)
S3method(func,default)
S3method(func,factor)
S3method(func,numeric)
export(func)
```

One way to fix this is to `:::`-reference the functions (since `::` doesn't work):

```r
#' @export
func.factor <- function(obj) {
  asnum <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(obj)))
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1]] <- if (anyNA(asnum)) substitute(newproj:::func.character) else substitute(newproj:::func.numeric)
  eval.parent(cl)
}
```

Which now works:

```r
detach("package:newproj")
devtools::install("~/newproj")
library(newproj)
func(5)
# [1] 25
func(factor("5"))
# [1] 25
func(factor("a"))
# [1] "5 times a"
```

But now, if I `R CMD check` the package, I get

```
> checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
  There are ::: calls to the package's namespace in its code. A package
    almost never needs to use ::: for its own objects:
    'func.character' 'func.numeric'
```

I can perhaps ignore the check `NOTE`, but I really prefer to clean up notes and such when possible. I'm trying to avoid something like:

```r
if (anyNA(asnum)) {
  func.character(obj)
} else func.numeric(obj)
```

perhaps for the wrong reasons though. Do more elegant solutions exist?

Comment: Great question. Couldn't you just have unexported methods that do the actual work for your S3 methods? You could call these directly inside your numeric / character methods and conditionally inside your factor method.

Comment: Good point, @AllanCameron. I had initially feared that doing so (when there are many other arguments in the functions) might defeat some basic assumptions such as the use of `missing(.)`, but that still works, so that argument goes away.  I guess I'm trying to keep stack-bloat by replacing a call on the stack instead of adding another. You may be right that that is the most direct way to avoid this. Thank you.

Comment: Explanation as to why I have avoided doing that in the past: the real function has 12+ arguments. When I add an argument to the original method, I have to add it to all classes functions for that method; it's clear to update the function definitions themselves, but I have at times missed one or two nested calls. To mitigate that risk, I found that the use of `cl <- match.call()` and `eval.parent(cl)` reduced my mistakes by keeping this churn to a minimum. Perhaps it's better to just accept the pain and do better testing. Thanks again @AllanCameron

Comment: But can't you still use `eval.parent` if your subcontracted / unexported functions have the same signature as your S3 generics? I admit I also like the "swapping function call with same parameters" idiom. I was fascinated when I first saw it inside some of the `stats` functions. I don't think I have used it myself inside any packages, maybe through forgetting about it, or lack of need, but I also wonder if it makes the code a little more opaque.

Comment: `eval.parent` is fine, except using `substitute(..)` means that it attaches the *symbol* of the function name. When it is evaluated in the parent (caller) frame, that function is not visible, so it fails. If I choose to instead do `cl[[1]] <- if (..) func.numeric ...` instead of `substitute(func.numeric)`, then later debugging (`debugonce(newproj:::func.numeric)`) presents the function *body*: `Browse[2]> where` returns `where 1: function(obj)  ...` instead of `where 1: func.numeric(factor("5"))` as I would hope.